# check carriage return is there in a given string

Tags: python, python-2.7

i,m reading some lines from a file and i'm checking whether each line has windows type of CRLF or not. If either '\n' or '\r' is absent in any line, it has to report an error. I tried with the below code, even if the line doesnt have '\r', it is not reporting any error

```
Open_file = open(File_Name,'r').readlines()
while Loop_Counter!= Last_Line:
        Line_Read = Open_file[Loop_Counter]
        if('\r\n' in Line_Read):
            pass
        else:
            print Loop_Counter
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
Open_file = open(File_Name,'rb').readlines()
```

you have to open file in binary mode

Answer (score 8):

This isn't working because `Loop_Counter` is never adjusted at all; whatever the initial value is, it's not changing and the `while` loop either runs indefinitely or never passes.  Your code is pretty unclear here; I'm not sure why you'd structure it that way.

What you're suggesting would be easier to do like this:

```py
infile = open(filename, 'rb')
for index, line in enumerate(infile.readlines()):
    if line[-2:] != '\r\n':
        print index
```

The `'rb'` argument is necessary to make sure the newlines are read as `\r\n` and not just as `\n`.

Comment: Loop_Counter is used properly in my code.But i forgot to include here. And it is works fine if i use 'rb'.

Answer (score 0):

Should it be

```
if ('\r' not in Line_Read or '\n' not in Line_Read): 
    print Loop_Counter
```

??
Also, as jdotjdot pointed out, Loop_Counter is not incremented at all.