# Why does grep see what Python cannot see ('\r\n')?

Tags: python, grep, binary, line-breaks

I execute the following command

```
grep $'\r\n' tmp.txt | wc -l
```

And as a result I get:

```
1000
```

So, I conclude that my file contains 1000 lines containing `\r\n`. Now I try to do the same in Python:

```
out = []
finp = 'tmp.txt'
i = 0
for line in open(finp, 'rb').readlines():
    if line[-2:] == '\r\n':
    #if '\r\n' in line:
        out.append(1)
    else:
        out.append(0)
print(sum(out))
```

And I get `0` as the result. What I do in Python is not exactly the same, because I do not check of a line **contains** `\r\n`. Instead of that I check if it **ends** with `\r\n`. However, I do not think that it is the reason of the difference (since I believe that in my case the lines ends with the `\r\n`).

So, my question is how to check if the line contains the `\r\n` combination. As you may noticed I try to run `if '\r\n' in line` but it causes an error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Second, I am not sure that it will help. Do I need to do something more to be sure that Python "sees" what grep does see?

Comment: Why is the file opened in bytes mode? You're comparing a bytes object with a string.

Comment: This is why I open it in the bytes mode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953639/check-carriage-return-is-there-in-a-given-string

Comment: Then use `b'\r\n'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to check if `\r\n` is in the line is to use

```
if b'\r\n' in line
```

In this way Python produced the same number of lines as grep.